# Don't work controls to play for two players

Tags: javascript, key, controls, class-method

```
// methods for key
 setControlsButton(){
    var _this = this;
    window.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 65) {
            _this.x -= _this.velX;
            } else if (e.keyCode === 68) {
            _this.x += _this.velX;
            } else if (e.keyCode === 87) {
            _this.y -= _this.velY;
            } else if (e.keyCode === 83) {
            _this.y += _this.velY;
        }
    }
}

setControlsArrow(){
    var _this = this;
    window.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            _this.x -= _this.velX;
            } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            _this.x += _this.velX;
            } else if (e.keyCode === 38d) {
            _this.y -= _this.velY;
            } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            _this.y += _this.velY;
        }
    }
}
```

method call

```
player1.draw();
player1.checkBounds();
player1.collisionDetect();
player1.setControlsButton();

player2.draw();
player2.checkBounds();
player2.collisionDetect();
player2.setControlsArrow();
// code
```

I want to control two players: arrow keys and 'wasd'. But only the last called method works, i.e. *setControlsArrow()*. Please help, how to make controls for two player in vanila js?

Answer (score 1):

By using `window.onkeydown`, you're overriding all other `keydown` event listeners on the `window`object. So when you call the second method, you delete the listener you set on the first one.

You should use `window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){...});` instead.